# upload_mimes not accepting CSV

Tags: uploads

Hi I am adding support for CSV uploads like so :

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes',  function ( $mime_types ) {

  $mime_types['csv']  = 'text/csv';

  return $mime_types;

});
```

How every when I try to upload the file I still get :

```
Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload anything except images, documents, audio or video files—and it's good for security, But in case you want to allow specific file type to upload in media library you will have to define `ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS`.

Put this code in `wp-config.php` file.

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

This code doesn't allow every user to upload every file type, though. Only administrators are allowed to upload whatever they want.

Source: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/new-wp-config-tweaks-you-probably-dont-know--wp-35396

https://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files